# regex or other way to fetch data from a line with variable entry

Tags: python, regex, string, split

in python, I am trying to fetch data from a line.
The lines look like:

```
 1.  cpasite=5 nsubl=4 cpatypes=3,4,5,6
 2.  cpasite=6 nsubl=2 cpatypes=7,8
 3.  cpasite=7 nsubl=4 cpatypes=9,10
 4.  cpasite=8 nsubl=2 cpatypes=11,12
 5.  cpasite=9 nsubl=6 cpatypes=13,14,15,16,17,18
```

I have regexed it as:

```
pattern=r'(\d+)\. \s* cpasite=(.*)\s* nsubl=(.*)\s* cpatypes=(.*)'
```

the problem is, I need those sites(e.g. 3,4,5,6) seperately, so that I can use them for my purpose. but given that the number is not fixed, i cant split(in my knowledge).

How I can use those cpasites ?

Comment: Did you mean `cpatypes`?

Comment: 1. Does your regexp extract `3,4,5,6` etc. correctly? 2. You *can* `split(",")`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use your `regex` and then take the 4th captured group which will be as:
'3,4,5,6'

You can then split that string on `,` to get your list of values that you can work with separately:

```
s = '3,4,5,6'
s = map(int, s.split(','))

print s
[3,4,5,6]

>>> print s[2]
5
```

Comment: but as i need this for all, possibly a list of lists?

Comment: yours was helpful and I added +1, but I was unable to solve my problem with that.
Can you kindly have a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222524/splitting-regex-result-in-python3

Answer (score 1):

Split is your friend.  Less regex == less complexity.

```
s = '1.  cpasite=5 nsubl=4 cpatypes=3,4,5,6'
sites = s.split('=')[-1]
sites = sites.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

**It should be:**

```
 pattern=r'(\d+)\. \s* cpasite=(.*)\s* nsubl=(.*)\s* cpatypes=(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*'
```

however for some reason it seems that

```
(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*
```

only captures the first cpatypes and the last one... **Seems a bug of the re module to me**.

**Turn arround:**

However if you know the maximum number of cpatypes you can have, then

```
pattern=r'(\d+)\. \s* cpasite=(.*)\s* nsubl=(.*)\s* cpatypes=(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?(?:,(\d+))?'
```

repeating

```
(?:,(\d+))?
```

as many times as needed (the maximum expected cpatypes), **worked for me**. Even so it is a bit ugly...